# Eclipse CDT cannot resolve uint8_t and the like

Tags: eclipse, avr, eclipse-cdt, indexer

I'm using Eclipse CDT Mars 4.5.0 20150621-1200 on Linux for a firmware project involving AVR microcontrollers. Eclipse is giving me errors like "Type 'uint8_t' could not be resolved".

I properly added `/usr/lib/avr/include` to Project properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes.

When I try to open the declaration of `uint8_t` in Eclipse I get the following offerings:

[image]

This suggests me that Eclipse detected 2 declarations and cannot decide which is the right one. It's strange to me because `/usr/include` is not featured under Paths and Symbols -> Includes.

How to fix this pain? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you included inttypes.h?

For most avr-gcc installations, you would need this include statement:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add the armcc path in the 'Library Paths' of the 'Paths and Symbols'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).